# OrientDB: Namespaces for classes?

Tags: orientdb

Other that using a string prefix, is there any method of providing namespaces for classes in OrientDB?

All of the built in classes have a "O" prefix, so the suggestion is that I should just prefix all of my classes with "Me" (or whatever) so that I don't call foul in future of a new class coming along that conflicts with something I've created that starts with "O".

Comment: I think it isn't possible natively.